# Returning the current project status (i.e., most recent date on Django ManyToMany relationship)

Tags: django, database-design, django-models, database-schema

### Schema Description

A project's status can change over time. In order to track the status over time, I've created a many-to-many relationship between the `Project` model and the `ProjectStatusType` model through the `ProjectStatus` intermediary table.

While this allows tracking a project's status over time, it increases the complexity of the schema such that retrieving the current status of a project or retrieving all open projects is more difficult.

[image]

### Use Case

I want to be able to return all projects that are in a given state, such as all `open` projects. For instance, when users go to http://www.example.com/projects, I'd like only the `open` projects to be displayed in a table by default.

### Questions

1. Should I denormalize the schema and add a `current_status` field in the `Project` model?
2. If I shouldn't denormalize, what strategy should I use to retrieve the current status for each project? Should I create a property on the `Project` model that retrieves the current status?

Comment: Totally unrelated, but did you create the image by hand, or do you have some kind of automated tool that creates this based on your models. It seems that way since it matches the colorscheme from the Django website and admin... and if so, I'd like to use that tool :).

Comment: @jro: I use OmngiGraffle Professional on OS X to create the drawings with the Django drawing stencil downloaded from Graffletopia.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to search on it, I would create a property on the Project model. You can use the `Max` function to `aggregate` to get the record with the newest date.

```
from django.db.models import Max

class Project(models.Model):
    [...]

    @property
    def status_date(self):
        return self.projectstatus_set.aggregate(newest=Max('status_date'))['newest']
```

This strategy is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/aggregation/).

If you need to do lookups, then you should denormalize and add a field to `Project`. You can keep it current using signals. You would want to add a `post_save` listener to your `ProjectStatus` field, which would set its project's date to the status'.

```
from django.db.signals import post_save

def update_status_date(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):
    project = instance.project
    project.status_date = max(project.status_date, instance.status_date)
    project.save()
post_save.connect(update_status_date, sender=ProjectStatus)
```

You can read more about signals [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/signals/).

======

EDIT: Since writing my original answer, the OP has clarified his question somewhat, and his clarification alters the example code for both of my strategies, although not their basic construction. I want to leave the original answer for those who may have needs more akin to the question I thought I was answering at the time.

In my first example, he doesn't really want the newest status_date itself, but rather the newest project status type. This would change the property substantially; you don't need to use a `MAX()` SQL construct at all; you just want the first record attached to this object when ordered by date descending:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    [...]

    @property
    def project_status(self):
        return self.status.order_by('-status_date')[0]
```

The use cases around this are still the same. If you will always get a project first and then want to know its current status, this is the right way to go about it. If you need to *index* projects by status, then you need to denormalize. This is still best done through signals, but instead of saving the date like I was doing in my example above, you probably want to save a description. The principle remains the same, though.

Comment: Yes, I am wanting to "*index* projects by status." For instance, I'd like to be able to get all projects that are in the `open` state or all projects in the `closed` state. Based on that use case, it seems like I need to denormalize. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah. Add a current status column in `Project` and use a post_save signal to write it.

Answer (score 0):

By your description, I'm assuming you're in fact using `ProjectStatus` as the `through` for your `ManyToManyField`, and that you're already storing extra data on the relationship with that model. If one of the items of extra data is not already the datetime when the that particular status was set, I would add that to your model.

You can then order `ProjectStatus` by that datetime, descending, so the first `ProjectStatus` returned will always be the most recent (current).

Comment: I updated the schema drawing to show that I am in fact using `ProjectStatus` as the `through` for the `ManyToManyField`. The only extra data store on that relationship in the `ProjectStatus` model is the `status_date` field to reflect when the status was originally set.