# Filtering projects by current status type when status is a ManyToManyField

Tags: django

For background see this SO question: [Returning the current project status (i.e., most recent date on Django ManyToMany relationship)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890103/returning-the-current-project-status-i-e-most-recent-date-on-django-manytoman)

As I was thinking about the problem, it sparked a question of my own. Essentially, you have something roughly similar to the following:

```
class StatusType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Project(models.Model):
    status = models.ManyToManyField(StatusType, through='ProjectStatusType')

class ProjectStatusType(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    status_type = models.ForeignKey(StatusType)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

To get the current status type for a particular project, you could do something like:

```
Project.status.order_by('-projectstatustype__created')[0]
```

But what if you wanted to get all projects whose current status is 'foo'?

```
Project.objects.filter(status__name='foo')
```

That would return projects who ever had a status of 'foo', whether or not it was the current status. You almost want to do something like (note the use of `current` in the filter):

```
Project.objects.annotate(current=Max('projectstatustype__created')).filter(status__name='foo', projectstatustype__created=current)
```

Obviously, that won't work because in that context, `current` is expected to be a Python variable within the current scope, but it got me wondering: is there some way to pass the same concept on though to the SQL, such that it will look for created dates that match the annotation that was just created?

**UPDATE**:

It was suggested by @akonsu to simply use the `ProjectStatusType` model, instead. However that doesn't really solve anything.

```
ProjectStatusType.objects.filter(statustype__name='foo')
```

Returns all `ProjectStatusType` with a status of 'foo'. You could then loop over the queryset and get each `Project` with the `project` attribute, but again, these will be projects that at some point in time had this status, not necessarily projects that have this status *currently*. Even if you tried something like:

```
ProjectStatusType.objects.filter(statustype__name='foo').order_by('-created')[0]
```

And then accessed the `project` attribute, that would merely give you the project that most recently received this status, not all projects that currently have the status.

Comment: why cannot you just use ProjectStatusType model directly?

Comment: You could, but that doesn't really solve the problem. See update in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

basically the question is how to filter a query set by comparing two of its fields: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model.

so your original query that uses annotations can be fixed:

`Project.objects.annotate(current=Max('projectstatustype__created'))
               .filter(status__‌​name='foo',
                       projectstatustype__created=F('current'))`

Comment: Nailed it on the head. I completely forgot about `F`. Question seems stupid now, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be there is a working solution with multiple joins and aggregation, but I'd think about denormalization: just add `cur_status` field to `Project` and update it with signals.